# Tableau Percentage calculation

Tags: tableau-api

I am learning Tableau using sample dataset `Sample Superstore`. I am trying to find out, For a given period let us say January 2012, what percentage of sales were shipped using a specific product container (e.g. Jumbo Box)

When containers are in Rows, I get 2.22% and when I flip row to column and vice-versa I get 9.17%. Would appreciate some inputs to clarify this.

2.22%

[image: 2.22%]

9.17%
[image: 9.17%]

Comment: compare the scope and direction of your table calculation before and after switch

Comment: Scope remains the same. Filtered by year 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use table calculation the values will differ according to the viz and what type of calculation you have used. For example `table down` will calculate from top to bottom and `table across` will calculate from left to right. Like this you will see many other options for calculations.

In below example I have used `running total` with `table across` that is direction from `Left to Right` column  values `(2014,2015,2016,2017,2018)`.

**Example:**
**Image1 - Original Data(without table calculation)**
[image: Image1-Original Data(without table calculation)]

**Data with table calculation - running total(table across)**

In below image, `Left to Right` values are `Ship Dates against Segments`. Look at the **Yellow** color highlighted row. Year `2015` for `Consumer Segment` the sales value is `40,656` but in the original data(Image1) it is `24,635`. The reason it is showing `40,656` is because table calculation is performed with `running total by table across(left to right)`, so the `original value 24,635 is added with previous Year's(2014) value 16,021`. Hence `16021 + 24635 = 40656`. It means `Left value(16021)` is added with the `Right value(24635)`. This pattern will continue till the right most value.
**Image2** 
[image: Image2]

**Columns and rows are switched**
In below image(Image3) `Left to Right` values are `Segments against Ship Dates`. The Columns and rows are switched. The value of `Corporate` Segment for the Year 2014 is changed to `25950(blue circle)` because the `left side value 16021` is `added with the original value 9929(Image1)`. 
**Image3**
[image]

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.